# Does CPIO produce platform dependant archives?

Tags: solaris, cpio

I made a CPIO archive with following command on Solaris 11 (SPARC):

```
 find .  | cpio -ov >/tmp/myarchive.cpio
```

I copied it to Intel based Solaris 11 machine and tried to extract using the following command

```
cpio -icvdu < myarchive.cpio
```

It gives me following error:

```
cpio: Not a cpio file, bad header.
1 errors
```

The MD5SUM hash matches and I can extract it on another SPARC machine.

My question, does CPIO produce platform dependant output? Is there any way to convert it?

I cannot use TAR at this moment, because the directory I am archiving has long symbolic links that are skipped by TAR command

Comment: Is your copy & paste correct in that you didn't create the archive with the "-c" option (use ASCII portable format) but you are telling it to expect that format for reading the archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the quoted commands are copy and pasted correctly, this seems to be a mistake in the choice of flags - you didn't create the archive with the "-c" option (use ASCII portable format) but you are telling it to expect that format for reading the archive.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by using GNU CPIO and with -c (use old ASCII portable format) option during creation of archive. I assume the -c option also works for Solaris CPIO.